# How to detect if item is selected in Google Maps API autocomplete list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I'm trying to achieve the following behavior.

When using Google Maps API's autocomplete, clicking with the mouse on an element in the list or pressing enter will select the desired element and fill in the input with necessary values. However, if you press enter while focus is still in the input element itself, nothing happens, so it's necessary to somehow solve that.

I have decided to solve that problem by selecting the first item from the autocomplete list:

```
$("#autocomplete").keypress(function(e){
  if(e.which == 13) {
    select-first-item();
  }
});
```

It works well, but the problem is that it will select the first item even if you use the down arrow on the keyboard, browse the autocomplete list and then press enter while e. g. 4th result is selected.

How to solve this? I have tried with `:focus`, but it doesn't seem very reliable. Sometimes it selected the first result, sometimes it selected the focused item from the list.

Google Maps adds class `pac-item-selected` to the item selected in the list, so my last try was based on checking for `length`.

```
$("#autocomplete").keypress(function(e){
  if ( $( ".pac-item-selected" ).length ) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
      select-first-item();
    }
  }
}
```

However, as soon as you press anything, the class goes away and checking for length doesn't work. If I use event.preventDefault, the whole functionalitiy doesn't work, since autocomplete is obviously based on keypress/keydown/... events.

I couldn't make Maps work in my fiddle properly, so I have adapted an old fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pbbhH/1222/

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

using place_changed event of autocomplete you can check place has been changed:

```
var input_source = document.getElementById('input_source');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input_source);
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
         // process
    });
```

Comment: I'm using place_changed, but for generating autocomplete list and populating location data (geometry.location). How would it be useful here, i. e. how can it make the distinction between enter stroke when there is an item focused/selected in the list and enter stroke without the list at all? Could you implement your solution with the fiddle I provided?

Comment: place_changed is a listener used by Maps API to detect changes in the input element. When a user types in the input, place_changed is triggered. It all works properly in my case, I'm using the same code as you provided. Please check the provided fiddle. The problem is that I can't distinguish if there is an element selected or not in the autocomplete list (with 'pac-item-selected' class) when the user presses the enter key.

Comment: do you want to get lat long of selected place?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @dhara-paramar solution:

Just wanted to add new shorter version according to Google Maps Api Documantation:

```
var input_source = document.getElementById('input_source');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input_source);

autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);

function fillInAddress() {
    //your process here
};
```